# escape <?php inside of a JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php

I **have to** echo the below JavaScript code with using only one `<?php` tag. How to escape `<?php` inside the echo?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawLatestTen() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode( $json ); ?>);

    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('ipt_dolt_ten_stat'));
    ac.draw(data, {
        title : '<?php _e( 'Last 30 days form submission statistics', 'ipt_dolt' ); ?>',
        height : 300,
        vAxis : {title : '<?php _e( 'Submission Hits', 'ipt_dolt' ) ?>'},
        hAxis : {title : '<?php _e( 'Date', 'ipt_dolt' ); ?>'},
        seriesType : 'bars',
        series : {<?php echo count( $json[0] ) - 2; ?> : {type : 'line'}},
        legend : {position : 'top'},
        tooltip : {isHTML : true}
    });
}

</script>
```

so the result is:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">

function drawLatestTen() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode( $json ); ?>);

    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(\'ipt_dolt_ten_stat\'));
    ac.draw(data, {
        title : \'<?php _e( \'Last 30 days form submission statistics\', \'ipt_dolt\' ); ?>\',
        height : 300,
        vAxis : {title : \'<?php _e( \'Submission Hits\', \'ipt_dolt\' ) ?>'},
        hAxis : {title : \'<?php _e( \'Date\', \'ipt_dolt\' ); ?>\'},
        seriesType : \'bars\',
        series : {<?php echo count( $json[0] ) - 2; ?> : {type : \'line\'}},
        legend : {position : \'top\'},
        tooltip : {isHTML : true}
    }); ?>
}

</script>'; ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to `echo` that code, just close your PHP code with `?>`, paste that code exactly as it is and then reopen your PHP code with `<?php`. This is valid, for example: `<?php $var = TRUE; if ( $var ) { ?><p>Hello world</p><?php } ?>`

Comment: @AlejandroIván I have to do that because of my obfuscator script.

Comment: You cant open a php tag inside another php tag. Cant do this `<?php <?php ?> ?>`

Comment: @OkeTega My obfuscator script doesn't support multiple `<?php` tag. The code have to be pure php with a single `<?php` tag.

Comment: Obfuscator? What year is it, 2001? Obfuscation is *not* security, and this script can't possibly be worth obscuring in the first place.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Who are you to judge whether the code worth obfuscation or not? Have you seen the full source code? That's how you expose your 2017 thinking to the world!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mixing php / js can be a bit confusing because the quotes can intersect.

Notice that we're using `"` and `'`. You might want to echo with `"` or with `'` depending on what you need to accomplish. echoing with `"` in php allows you to use variables in the string, ie: `echo "hello {$username}"` the lamdas (`{}`) aren't required, but many devs prefer them.

Here's an *incomplete* example to get you started. You just echo it all at once and concatenate with `.` for strings in php.

```
<?php 
$title = translate( 'Submission Hits', 'ipt_dolt' );
$date = translate( 'Date', 'ipt_dolt' );
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawLatestTen() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( '. json_encode( $json ) .' );

    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('ipt_dolt_ten_stat'));
    ac.draw(data, {
        title : '<?php _e( 'Last 30 days form submission statistics', 'ipt_dolt' ); ?>',
        height : 300,
        vAxis : {title : "'. $tite .'"},
        hAxis : {title : "'.$date.'"}, // notice two quotes, double to denote a string in js and singles to break/concatenate the php output. (that's where things get tricky.)
        seriesType : 'bars',
        series : { '. (count( $json[0] ) - 2) .' : {type : 'line'}},
        legend : {position : 'top'},
        tooltip : {isHTML : true}
    });
}
</script>'; ?>
```

Edit: Special thanks to [@wh1t3h4ck5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679733/wh1t3h4ck5) & [@jh1711](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7401610/jh1711) for helping me tweak this.

Comment: I'll also add, that depending on you might have trouble with multi-line strings in php. Pretty sure that's mainly when using single quotes (as I have above).

Comment: `{}` are required because in practice most data aren't coming from one-dimensional variables, e.g.  `{$x->y}`, `{$a["x"]}` so it's good practice to use it even in `{$a}` case (but true, not required for this last case).

Comment: Your direction is correct. But you misuse the `_e` function, which is the wordpress alias for `echo translate`. You can just use `translate` with the same arguments. BTW: The title needs to be handled in the same way. After that it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks sincerely @jh1711 I'm glad to know that!

Comment: And @Wh1T3h4Ck5 no kidding? I didn't know that and ... I've likely cast multi-dimensional variables to one-dimensional to avoid that problem in the past. Very much appreciate the lesson! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @admcfajn answered, that is the popper way to solve it but sometimes I have to do these changes through thousands lines of code so I usually change it using regex. I ended up with this solution:

- Replace all `<?php` tags with `';`
- Replace all `?>` tags with `echo '`
- In JavaScript code blocks, escape the single quote `'` using `\'`
- In JavaScript code blocks, break the long `echo` function into several echo functions.

I did it this way and it works fine.

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawLatestTen() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(';
        echo json_encode($json);
echo ');

    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(\'ipt_dolt_ten_stat\'));
    ac.draw(data, {
        title : \'';
        _e('Last 30 days form submission statistics', 'ipt_dolt');
echo '\',
        height : 300,
        vAxis : {title : \'';
        _e('Submission Hits', 'ipt_dolt');
echo '\'},
        hAxis : {title : \'';
        _e('Date', 'ipt_dolt');
echo '\'},
        seriesType : \'bars\',
        series : {';
        echo count($json[0]) - 2;
echo ' : {type : \'line\'}},
        legend : {position : \'top\'},
        tooltip : {isHTML : true}
    });
}

</script>
        ';
```